# Removing support for web in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building a mobile app using react-native/ expo, and I was wondering if there is a way to drop support for the web, so the app cannot be run in a web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Web JS` code is automatically stripped when bundled for other platforms. You can still disable the ability to open automatically from the `Expo CLI` by defining the platforms array in the `app.json` and only adding `ios` and `android`.

You can always remove `react-dom` and `react-native-web` from the `package.json`, this will be the default in the future since the `CLI` can automatically add them if needed.